# Redmine upgrade via svn not working

Tags: svn, redmine, updates

I'm running Redmine 2.1.6 and trying to update (after backing everything up) to the latest (2.3.0 and 2.2.4 as of this writing) by simply [following the instructions here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade) and doing an `$ svn update`.  I've successfully done this in the past with no problems.  However, this time, the `$ svn update` is not pulling any new code.

I can still do a fresh checkout of version 2.3 by doing

```
$ svn co http://svn.redmine.org/redmine/branches/2.3-stable redmine-2.3
```

and this works, but the update from the existing installation doesn't work.  Anyone have any clues why it's not pulling the new code?

Answer (score 0):

Try `svn revert PATH` followed  by `svn update`, where path is the file path to what you are trying to update